# Branch sendSMS() results undefined

Tags: branch.io

I have integrated Branch's sendSMS() for a client. It has worked in the past but seems to have stopped. I am fairly certain that it is integrated correctly as I can get the callback to return errors when I try too many times in an hour.

```
var phone = form.phone.value;
var linkData = {
        tags: [],
        channel: 'Website',
        feature: 'TextMeTheApp',
        data: utm_attr
};

var callback = function(err, result) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(result)
        if (err) {
            analytics.track('text_to_app_error', {phone: phone});
            document.getElementById('phone-capture-modal-flash').innerHTML = 'Something went wrong, please try again.';
            document.getElementById('phone-capture-modal-flash').style.color = 'red';
            document.getElementById('phone-capture-flash').innerHTML = 'Something went wrong, please try again.';
            document.getElementById('phone-capture-flash').style.color = 'red';
        }
        else {
            analytics.track('text_to_app_success', {phone: phone});
            document.getElementById('phone-capture-modal-flash').innerHTML = 'Text sent.';
            document.getElementById('phone-capture-modal-flash').style.color = 'green';
            document.getElementById('phone-capture-flash').innerHTML = 'Text sent.';
            document.getElementById('phone-capture-flash').style.color = 'green';
        }
};
branch.sendSMS(phone, linkData, {}, callback);
```

The `err` in callback seems to return properly, as I can get `429 (Too Many Requests)` in console,  but `result` is undefined when I use different number. Any ideas?

Side note, branch settings show `Web SDK not integrated` warning, but it's integrated as the docs show.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you saw that error message because your requests hit rate limits of Text Me the App. Branch enforces the following limits when sending SMS through Branch:

- 5 texts to the same number within an hour.
- 100 texts from the same IP within an hour.
- The number the SMS has to be delivered to, must be in the same country the SMS is being sent from.

You can also find this information about this at [docs.branch.io/web/text-me-the-app/#faq](https://docs.branch.io/web/text-me-the-app/#faq).

Please contact [support@branch.io](http://support@branch.io) if you have any further questions.